# Backbone.js: Using the same model value to set another value of same model

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm trying to set a property of a model using another property but I am getting `undefined`.

This is the example:

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        status: "incomplete",
        relationalStatus: this.status,
    },
});
```

When I try getting the value using `todoItem.attributes`. I just see an empty string in the `relationlStatus` value.

Why is not getting the value?

Comment: Do you expect it have `"incomplete"` value? [`this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) in your code doesn't refer to your model. This is not how JavaScript work.

Comment: Using `this.model.status`doesn't work neither. I'm just asking how can I use the same value on both properties as I am a little lost with the Backbone API

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to set this during the [initialize](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-constructor) phase. `this.status` is referring to the outer scope, it's not currently scoped within the model.

Example of using initialize.

http://jsbin.com/wuqef/1/edit

```
var TodoItem = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        status: "incomplete",
        relationalStatus: null,
    },

  initialize: function() {

    // Set the relationalStatus to the status property
    this.set('relationalStatus', this.get('status'));

  }

});
```

Comment: Thanks. This has worked for me even thought I guess is not the best way. For now is working. Really appreciated.